# Ranking over each matrix column's sort in julia

Tags: sorting, matrix, julia, ranking

I have a matrix (m) of scores for 4 students on 3 different exams.

```
4 3 1
3 2 5
8 4 6
1 5 2
```

I want to know, for each student, the exams they did best to worse on. Desired output:

```
1 2 3
2 3 1
1 3 2
3 1 2
```

Now, I'm new to the language (and coding in general), so I read GeeksforGeeks' [page on sorting in Julia](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-contents-of-a-data-frame-in-julia/) and tried

```
mapslices(sortperm, -m; dims = 2)
```

However, this gives something subtly different: a matrix of each row being the *index* of the sorting.

```
1 2 3
3 1 2
1 3 2
2 3 1
```

Perhaps it was obvious, but I now realize this is not actually what I want, but I cannot find a built-in function/fast way to complete this operation. Any ideas? Preferably something which doesn't iterate through items in the matrix/row, as in reality my matrix is very, very large. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such functionality is provided by StatsBase.jl. Here is an example:

```
julia> using StatsBase

julia> m = [4 3 1
            3 2 5
            8 4 6
            1 5 2]
4×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 4  3  1
 3  2  5
 8  4  6
 1  5  2

julia> mapslices(x -> ordinalrank(x, rev=true), m, dims = 2)
4×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3
 2  3  1
 1  3  2
 3  1  2
```

You might want to use other rank, depending on how you want to split ties, see [here](https://juliastats.org/StatsBase.jl/stable/ranking/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out something which works!

Run `m_index_rank = mapslices(sortperm, -m; dims = 2)` on the matrix and get a ranking for each row through index. Then, realizing this is, in each row, an inverse permutation away from the desired output, run `mapslices(invperm, m_index_rank; dims = 2)` for the desired result.

In one line, this is `mapslices(r -> invperm(sortperm(r, rev=true)), m; dims=2)` over the desired matrix `m`. `dims = 2` is to carry out the operation row-wise.

I'm marking this resolved for now, but please let me know if there are cleaner/faster ways to do this.

Edit: Replaced my syntactically clunky `mapslices(invperm, mapslices(sortperm, -m; dims = 2); dims = 2)` with a more natural one, thanks to @phipsgabler

Comment: I have to admit I can't follow the semantics of your problem, but I'd write the solution as `mapslices(r -> invperm(sortperm(r, rev=true)), m; dims=2)`.